# Tensorflow - How to know configuration of loaded model like weight shape so that I can create that graph in advance?

Tags: tensorflow

I have different saved models where some of them use different configurations namely, the number of neurons and the optimizer type (Adam or RMS). Is there a way to know about these parameters during loading so that I can change the tensor shape or optimizer in the graph? Thanks.

Currently, I am facing this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both 
tensors to match. lhs shape= [186,256] rhs shape= [186,32]
```

I know I can change the shape manually but I wanted to know about a way to do this in the code. Also, if this is not possible, is there a way to save models in the future where I can know about their configuration in advance so that I don't get this error? Thanks.

Comment: You can write and restore full models as `MetaGraph`s, instead of recreating them. Have you taken a look at [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph)?

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it during my search. I think that is a great solution for the future.